# How can I get Google Voice SMS notifications?

Tags: sms, notifications, google-voice

I have an iPhone 4 with the Google Voice app. However I don't get notifications at all, I've tried everything! If I want to check if I received a text I have to go into the app and press the refresh button.

How can I get notifications working?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings -> Notifications -> Google Voice. You'll see underneath the the 'Google Voice' line what's being pushed for notifications, chances are yours will say 'Off'. Just tap it and pick which ones you want to happen when you receive a SMS.

Comment: Otherwise, it's an issue in Google's server. Not much you can do.